# Having background on button when clicked on but not hovering vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

### Explanation

I have an icon in a button that when clicked opens a menu.
If I want to get the menu correctly under button I need to change the height, because there doesn't seem to be another option (margin doesn't work). But then I get A background hover effect while not hovering over the button.

**So to understand.
Once I click on the button but don't hover over the button I get the effect.**

The shape is because I changed the height en width.
Background-color: transparant !important; Doens't work

[image: Photo of the problem]

[image: GIF of the problem]

**This is the component file**

```html
<template>
  <v-menu
          :close-on-click="true"
          offset-y
          transition="slide-y-transition"
          v-model="language_menu_open"
          return-value="language_menu_open = false">
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <v-btn
              v-on="on"
              v-ripple="false"
              icon
              depressed
              class="language-button">
          <v-icon>{{functionMenu(language_menu_open)}}</v-icon>
          <v-icon style="margin-right: 10px !important;">mdi-web</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </template>
    <v-list class="language-dropdown">
      <v-list-item
                  v-for="language in languages"
                  :key="language.title"
                  v-ripple="false"
                  @click="language">
        <v-list-item-title>{{language.title}}</v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item>
    </v-list>
  </v-menu>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "Languages",
    data() {
      return {
        language_menu_open: false,
        languages: [
          {title: "Nederlands"},
          {title: "English"},
          {title: "Deutsch"}
        ],
        functionMenu: function chevronChanger(menu_state) {
          if (menu_state) {
            return "mdi-chevron-up"
          } else {
            return "mdi-chevron-down"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  .language-button {
    height: 45px !important;
    width: 25px !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
  }

  .language-button:hover {
    background-color: transparent !important;
  }

  .language-button:hover:before {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    display: none !important;
  }

  .language-dropdown {
    padding: 0 !important;
  }

  .language-dropdown:hover:before {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated that your primary goal is correct positioning of the menu below the button. Instead of changing the height/width of the button, you should use the `nudge-top`, `nudge-bottom`, `nudge-right`, and/or `nudge-left` props of the `v-menu` component. These allow you to precisely tune the positioning of the menu. For example, if you want to move the menu down (further below the button), set the `nudge-bottom` prop to the number of pixels you want it to move. See documentation [here.](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/#api) Using this approach, you don't need to modify the hover effect of your button, which will result in a better user experience.

Also, there is one portion of your template that is inefficient. For one of the icons, you have `{{functionMenu(language_menu_open)}}`. If possible, you should not use methods in a template except as event handlers, because methods break Vue's reactivity engine. In this case, it would be much better to define a `computed` property, like this:

```
computed: {
  buttonChevron: function() {
    if (this.language_menu_open) {
      return "mdi-chevron-up"
    } else {
      return "mdi-chevron-down"
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in your template, instead of `{{functionMenu(language_menu_open)}}`, use `{{ buttonChevron }}`. This will have the same effect as your current function, but Vue will handle the changes much more efficiently. (In this particular component, the change will be negligible, but it's a good habit to build.) You can read more about computed properties [here.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties)

Comment: Thank you kindly

Comment: Inplace of props I use methods now. And I call the function with {{ buttonChevron() }}.
Props doesn't work

Comment: I apologize, instead of `prop`, I should have written `computed`. (I don't know what I was thinking) I have updated my answer accordingly. As I mentioned before, you should avoid methods in the template except for event handlers. Your application will be much more efficient using `computed` properties instead of methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
.language-button:active {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: Problem still occurs.

Comment: can you host it somewhere and share the link?

Comment: Not possible at the moment

Comment: inspect the button, and see if the class ```language-button``` is there or not.